# how to collect only emails from related table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

i want to send emails to client multiple email id
i am collective email data like this

```
$emails = EmailClient::whereHas('client', function ($query) use($client){
                $query->where('id', $client->id);
            })->get();
```

[image: Email Data]

now i want to add collected email in array

```
$mail = Mail::to([$emails->email])->send(new SendInvoice($client));
```

Getting Error help me for sort out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For single email you can use `first` method

```
 $emails = EmailClient::whereHas('client', function ($query) use($client){
       $query->where('id', $client->id);
 })->select("email")->first();
```

If you want all email from table as array then use `pluck`

```
$emails = EmailClient::whereHas('client', function ($query) use($client){
       $query->where('id', $client->id);
 })->pluck("email");
```

And pass like this

```
$mail = Mail::to($emails)->send(new SendInvoice($client));
```